# Playing Flash video using cefsharp or Geckofx

Tags: winforms, flash, video, geckofx, cefsharp

I'm putting together a simple winforms app for playing videos from the web for my kids.  I've explored two options so far but I'm having problems with both of them:

**cefsharp**: Playing videos wasn't a problem, but it would not persist cookies (even with the CachePath set), so I would have to log into the web sites each time.  This would not be very user-friendly.

**GeckoFX**: No matter what site I go to (youtube for example), flash videos will not play.  I get a bank section on the page where the video goes.  Based on other questions, I tried adding the line "Gecko.GeckoPreferences.Default["extensions.blocklist.enabled"] = false;" right after the initialize statement, but that did not work.  I'm running xulrunner-33.0.2 and GeckoFx-Windows-33.0-0.2.

Any ideas on how to get either solution working would be appreciated.

*UPDATE*:
I found this site https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/issue/14/plugin-flash-not-working-since-xulrunner which stated to turn off the "Visual Studio hosting process" for the project and now YouTube video play with GeckoFX, but no videos play off xfinitytv's site (http://xfinitytv.comcast.net/watch-live-tv/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug has recently been fixed in CefSharp to make this possible.  See this issue: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/843

What should work is:

- setting `CachePath`
- set the `persist_session_cookies` command line argument
- after `OnContextInitialized`, call `Cef.SetCookiePath`

You'll need to use the latest version `39.0.1` to get access to the `OnContextInitialized` delegate.

Comment: second param of SetCookiePath is persistSessionCookies, so hopefully that's enough and no command line argument is needed.

Comment: Looks like setting CachePath and persist_session_cookies worked.  I didn't need to call the SetCookiePath method.  Thanks!